# Creating user for only one site in wordpress multisite setup

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have setup a wordpress multisite.

Site-1: http://example.com/(main site)

Site-2: http://example.com/site2

Custom User roles:

1. Business Owner
2. Employee

Business Owner can log in to the site-1. Only Business Owner can add his employee on site-2 so he can access the site-2 without log in again. I mean he must be logged in on site-2 if he login to site-1.
Site-2 is for the world. People can register but the login should be restricted for then on site-1.

Comment: you could look into "Single sign on" plugins.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer. At any rate, if the owner visits the Add User page on the second site's dashboard they can create users for that site only.